# Command binding to relay command not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I'm trying to develop a simple register in C# with WPF. I have buttons for my products and if they are pressed (via Keyboard shortcut or mouse button) the product is ordered.
I don't know how much products I have (will be loaded from the database) so a fixed solution is not what I want.
I've managed to display those buttons via a `Listbox` bound to the objects.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <UniformGrid>
            <Button Template="{DynamicResource ButtonBaseControlTemplate1}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Command="{Binding OrderCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding PictureUrl}" />
                </Button.Background>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="30"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 25, 0, 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Shortcut}" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </Button>
        </UniformGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Binding a `Command` does not work. If I click on the button, nothing happens. If I use the `Clicked` event, everything works fine, but I need the object which is bound to the button as parameter.

Here's my command property:

```
public RelayCommand OrderCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand((p) => MessageBox.Show("Test"), (p) => true);
    }
}
```

If everything would work as intended, there should be a `MessageBox` displaying "Test".

Thanks for your help in advance.

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Is the command in the same viewmodel as e.g. the binded name?

Comment: Where is `OrderCommand` defined? Where do you specify `DataContext`? Also you create new instance of `OrderCommand` with each get

Comment: `OrderCommand` is defined in `MainWindowViewModel` which is set as `DataContext` of this view.

Comment: So `OrderCommand` is defined in the same class as `PictureUrl`, `Name`, `Price` and `Shortcut` and these fields display fine?

Comment: No `PictureUrl`, `Name`, ... are properties of my class `Product`. In my `MainWindowViewModel` is an `ObservableCollection<Product>` which stores all those objects. In my `View` I display these objects in a `ListView` and instead of displaying a text or sth. similar I display buttons. These buttons now need one `RelayCommand`, in my case `OrderCommand` and the Button/Object in the `ListView` as parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to update your command binding to find it in your Window/Usercontrol datacontext

Assuming Command is in Windows DataContext

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.OrderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the datacontext of your button. As it is now, the datacontext is the object in the listview. What you want is to use the datacontext of your listview.

Something like that

```
Datacontext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
```

Comment: Executing the `Command` works, but I don't want to change the `DataContext`, because now all my display members are gone (like Price, Name, ...) and I don't get the correct object as parameter if I execute the `Command`.

Comment: You are right. I did not notice that many properties of the button were bound to properties of the object in the list. But now you have the idea

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have any idea right now.... with your solution I can execute the command, but I don't get the correct parameter type (type is `MainWindowViewModel` instead of `Product`) and my display properties don't show up...