# Dynamically add KeyBindings to Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, key-bindings

As you can see on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045771/command-binding-to-relay-command-not-working) I need dynamic buttons. Now I need to add some `KeyBinding`s to those buttons. The shortcuts are stored in my `Product` class as string.
I tried using a `ListBox`/`ListView` like I used for creating my buttons, but I can't add KeyBindings there.

Example:
Button is bound to object "Coke" where "C" is the shortcut. If I click on this button my `OrderCommand` command is executed and my bound object is used as its parameter. The same should work if I press "C".

Also I need it to work with dupes, let's say I have two products with the shortcut "C", and if I press "C" not the first button is pressed. Pressing "C" will switch between those two buttons and if I press enter, the `Command` will be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restyle buttons inside the list control to set their InputBindings

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Buttons}>
    <ListBox.Resources>
         <Style x:Key="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{x:Type Button}">
              <Setter Property="Button.InputBindings"/>
                   <Setter.Value>
                        <KeyBinding Key="C" Command="{Binding OrderCommand}" />     
                   </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
         </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that Buttons have a `InputBindings` property.
But unfortunately I have still one problem:
I have to click the button first and then I'm able to execute the command via key.
My application needs to be fully controllable via keyboard, so I need KeyBindings which work on the first keypress.

Comment: Seems like your view model knows about buttons anyway, so, I would catch the KeyPress on the window and set the focus on the right button from view model.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define the Keybinding for the command in DataContext that you can do like below:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Key="C" Command="{Binding OrderCommand}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Is there no way to bind a `KeyBinding` to a button?
My buttons are objects and they are used as parameters.
And I don't know how many buttons I have (depends on DB data), maybe 10 buttons, maybe just 3.